# Why is there no sample.default() function

Tags: r

I have a process where I want to select randomly from vectors that can occasionally be an integer of length one.

`sample(x,1)` returns a sample from the vector `x` when it is longer than 1. When `x` is length one it calls a `sample.int(x)` function that samples from integers less than `x+1`. Is there a way of forcing R to sample the single integer value as it would if the integer was a character?

to make things concrete:

```
sample(4,1)
>3
sample("4",1)
>"4"
#I want a simpler way of getting
as.numeric(sample(as.character(4),1)))
>4
```

This behavior is noted in the r inferno at 8.2.33 and it suggests the `as.numeric(as.character())` kludge.

It takes half the help page to explain this behavior. Is there a reason for this besides a long history of confusing behavior?

Comment: I assumed your question was asking for how to make `sample(4, 1)` always return 4 but then you started talking about characters and stuff, so I don't know what you're asking now

Comment: @rawr if the first argument is a character it behaves the way I want. You can call sample int and subset or you can set the first argument to a character-then set it back. Both seem kludgy.

Comment: the answer below is the proper way to do it

Answer (score 2):

recommended way for this is writing a wrapper function to handle unit length lists

```
resample <- function(x, ...) x[sample.int(length(x),...)]
```

see [the examples here](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/sample)

```
> resample(4,1)
[1] 4
```